# All content inside iBooks disappeared

Tags: macos, high-sierra, books

Title is self-explenatory. I really didn't do anything special, all epubs, PDFs etc are gone. I restarted the computer, same result. I have only used it from my MacBook, no iPhone, iPad or anything else.

I checked time machine at `username>library>contents>com.apple.BKAgentService>data>documents>ibooks>books` and weirdly I could only find books starting from many months ago and not sooner. For at least the last 3-4 backups this folder was empty, which is insane as I use iBooks every day and that definitely wasn't the case until now.

I restored these books, copy and pasted them at the present time `username>library>contents>com.apple.BKAgentService>data>documents>ibooks>books` folder but to no avail.

This is so weird as we're talking about hundreds of books!

Is there a standard dumb thing I may have unknowingly done for this to occur? What else can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct would be to try logging out of the iBooks Store and then logging back in. You can do this as follows:

1. Launch iBooks
2. Go to Store > Sign Out
3. Wait about 30 seconds and then go to Store > Sign In...
4. Enter your Apple ID and Password
5. Click on <kbd>Sign In</kbd>
6. Click on <kbd>Get Started</kbd>
7. iBooks should now populate with all your books, PDFs etc.

Comment: tried it but nothing. its so so so weird. in the end i restored a folder from the timemachine and opened all the epubs all at once, so they automatically returned to their place in ibooks. they even filed themselves at the collections i had set up. thanks for you input tho dude.